# I can't tame an ocelot 1.14.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I feed the ocelot and the hearts come up but it doesn't change into anything, it just stays an ocelot. Can anyone help me on what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Ocelots can't be tamed in 1.14. There are [cats](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Cat) that spawn in villages which can be tamed.

Comment: @cherryblossom Ocelots can be tamed. They just don't become cats. All that happens is they get a red collar and don't run away from you.

Comment: @SkyPaul Ok. I should have checked the wiki before I commented.

Answer (score 0):

in 1.14, cats cannot be tamed from ocelots.
you will have to find a stray cat in a village and feed it fish to tame it.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cat